How to keyframe custom property on all selected objects at once
I am working with Blender and have a question regarding keyframing multiple items with custom properties created using geometry nodes. Specifically, I am looking to keyframe a shared property for several selected items all at once.
To provide more context:
Custom Properties with Geometry Nodes: I have created custom properties using geometry nodes that are applied to multiple objects.
Keyframing Requirement: I want to select several of these objects simultaneously and add keyframes to a shared property across all of them at once, rather than individually keyframing each object.
I am not sure if Blender has a built-in function for this purpose. If not, could you please guide me on how to achieve this? Any scripts, add-ons, or workflows that you recommend would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your assistance!

After digging around for a bit, I managed to use a python script to achieve this.
So here's how it works, in case anyone has the same problem.
If you have a custom property created, and you'd like to keyframe it for all selected items sharing that property, i don't think there's a native wat to do this in Blender.
So what you need to do is, go into the scripting workspace and paste this script in there:
import bpy

# Define the custom property name and the initial value you want to set
property_name = "Opacity"
initial_value = 1.0  # Change this to the value you want to set
frame_number = bpy.context.scene.frame_current  # Change this to the frame you want to keyframe

# Get the selected objects
selected_objects = bpy.context.selected_objects

# Loop through each selected object
for obj in selected_objects:
    # Add the custom property if it doesn't exist
    if property_name not in obj:
        obj[property_name] = initial_value
    
    # Set the custom property value
    obj[property_name] = initial_value
    
    # Insert a keyframe for the custom property at the current frame
    obj.keyframe_insert(data_path=f'["{property_name}"]', frame=frame_number)

print(f"Custom property '{property_name}' set and keyframed for {len(selected_objects)} objects at frame {frame_number}.")

Replace "Opacity" in line 4 with the name of your custom property, then click on run, and that should do it.
Hope this helps someone.
Cheers

Hi, thanks for the answer. Was this generated by AI, chat assistants or otherwise with help from large language models? According to our site rules decided by the community through democratic voting, we do not currently accept answers generated by artificial intelligence, chat assistants or otherwise with help from large language models. If that is the case here, we'd kindly ask you to delete the post so as not to infringe the rules. Thanks for understanding
